# Generate String array subset with length <= 5

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, arraylist

I've got an array of String in Java. I'd like to generate a List of String arrays that contains all the sets of String with length <=5. For example, if

`String[] s1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}`

I want the result as:

```
List<String[]> s2 = {{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}, {"a", "d"}, {"b", "c"}, {"b", "d"}, {"c", "d"}, {"a", "b", "c"}, ...}
```

but I can't figure out how I can generate it automatically.

Comment: Can you clarify? You have stopped at 2 not 5.

Comment: @pbabcdefp - I guess he has done it manually and expects code to do it :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Ok, but there are only 4 elements in the original array. This definitely needs clarifying.

Comment: @pbabcdefp - Ya.. This I agree

Comment: @pbabcdefp sorry, i forgot ellipsis (:

Comment: you are looking for Bounded variation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code:

```
    ...
    String[] cols = ... //linea in input
    Set<String> subSet= new HashSet<String>();
    Set<Set<String>> sets = new HashSet<Set<String>>();

    //popolo l'insieme - escludo la data
    for(int i=1; i<cols.length; i++){
        subSet.add(cols[i]);
    }


    // creo l'insieme delle parti e popolo
    sets = powerSet(subSet);

 public static Set<Set<String>> powerSet(Set<String> originalSet) {

    Set<Set<String>> sets = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
    if (originalSet.isEmpty()) {
        sets.add(new HashSet<String>());
        return sets;
    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(originalSet);
    String head = list.get(0);
    Set<String> rest = new HashSet<String>(list.subList(1, list.size()));
    for (Set<String> set : powerSet(rest)) {
        if(set.size() < 5){
            Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();
            newSet.add(head);
            newSet.addAll(set);
            sets.add(newSet);
            sets.add(set);
        }
    }

    return sets;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a K-subset algorithm implementation. I'm sure they exist in maths libraries, or you could code your own.

S1 is your set (or alphabet) and s2 is the set of subsets up to length k (5).

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own generator I guess, or use some library for permutations/combinations, there should be plenty of math libs that can do so. Example of own implementation is here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41510/calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-given-characters

In my opinion example in link is exactly what you need - just change input array and length. Also author puts it in one string, and I see you want to have it in array of arrays, so output also should be changed

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you idea to solve this problem.

Start from an empty output string.One by one add all characters to prefix. For every character added, print all possible strings with current prefix by recursively calling for k equals to k-1.

Here K is the length in your case 1 to 5.